# share one single post on different sites in multisite network

Tags: wordpress, share, multisite

I have a multisite installation for one of my client. Now i want to add a news article which is a custom post type, but this news article must be shown through out my other site too.

Does any plugin help to sort this issue. bcoz i'm pretty much confused since i m new to this multisite enviorment.

In Simple words, its just that when u add post in site A, that post should also be able to seen on site B, by means of any sharing method

Comment: anything you have tried so far? are you getting any error?

Comment: sorry for replying late.
i have tried for few plugins say Wordpress Scraper, Post Content Shortcodes, WordPress MU Sitewide Tags Pages

but didnt work,